# Is the filename general.sql reserved in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have run into a somewhat weird thing.I am running my queries from a file name on windows

like `source c:\sql\general.sql` but that fails

```
mysql> source c:\sql\general.sql
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11, for Win32 (x86)

Connection id:          6
Current database:       joins
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 5 days 2 hours 53 min 45 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 167  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 86  Flush tables: 1  Open ta
bles: 62  Queries per second avg: 0.000
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sourc
e c:ql' at line 1
    ->
```

This the query

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

However,when i try running the same query but this time naming my file `stuff.sql`

```
mysql> source c:\sql\stuff.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.65 sec)
```

Is this a usual error?

Update

`source c:\sql\\general.sql` produces this error

```
mysql> source c:\sql\\general.sql
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11, for Win32 (x86)

Connection id:          6
Current database:       joins
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 5 days 3 hours 42 min 4 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 192  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 97  Flush tables: 1  Open ta
bles: 62  Queries per second avg: 0.000
--------------

ERROR:
Unknown command '\\'.
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sourc
e c:ql\\general.sql' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: No but I think the antislash is

Comment: `near 'source c:ql' at line 1` you probably need to use the other slash or escape your backslash `source c:/sql/stuff.sql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the forward slash:

```
mysql> source c:/sql/general.sql
```

I'll never forgive Microsoft for using a metacharacter for their default directory separator.

Answer (score 1):

`\g` is used in MYSQL as an output formatting character. You'd need to double-escape, e.g.

```
source c:\sql\\general.sql
```